# Is it proper to use the phrase "In conjunction with" in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to phrase a sentence to say do **something A** along with **something B**. I do not want to use *along with* because both the process are extremely co-dependent and for the same reason I do not want to use *in parallel to*. Would *in conjunction with* be a better choice?

Lets take a simple example.

> To use the toothbrush, press the <kbd>button **A**</kbd> along with
>   <kbd>button **B**</kbd>.

Is the statement still valid when I write

> To use the toothbrush, press the <kbd>button **A**</kbd> in conjunction with <kbd>button **B**</kbd>

Comment: Do Something A while simultaneously doing Something B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were writing it, I'd use the following format:

> To use the toothbrush, press buttons A & B.

But you could also consider

> To use the toothbrush, press Button A + Button B

if you needed to keep "button *x*" separate.

Answer (score 1):

> To use the toothbrush, press the button A in conjunction with button B

That is certainly valid and unambiguous. Another possibility is,

> To use the toothbrush, simultaneously press button A and button B.

There must be hundreds of possible sentences you could use.